Dymola division by zero during initialization, how to debug
I have a Modelica model that fails to initialize, with below division by zero error message:
Error: The following error was detected at time: 0
Model error - division by zero: (0.0) / (0.0) = (0) / (0)
Error: Integrator failed to start model.

Is there a way to also see the names of variables involved, or nonlinear block ID (like initialization.nonlinear[3]), or class and line of code?

Check every division operation in your model that involves time or a proxy for time. Really need to see the model code to be able to comment further.  Or as a really quick and dirty fix start time at 1e-9 (or some other small non-zero value).

Thanks, good idea. Start time of 1e-9 still gives the same error, so this is not a division by time.

Can you post some code of the model? I would expect the error message to be a bit more extensive. Is this all the output?

It is a customer model, I can build a smaller reproducer once I found the root cause. This is all the output.

Hopefully there are not too many divisions in it. Search for them and think very hard. If the error message is taken at face value it is  actually 0.0/0.0 with numerator and denominator both zero sort of fail that sin(x)/x might give if it wasn't coded defensively.

Still a bit puzzled that there is no additional output....
Still, one way to find the issue could be to set Advanced.OutputModelicaCode = true; which will generate dsmodel.mof in the working directory. This is at least a single place to look for the error. Additionally it could help to set Evaluate = true; and Advanced.EvaluateAlsoTop = true;. With a bit of luck you can search for 0/0 or something similar.

It is a customer model that was originally built in Twinbuilder, dsmodel.mof has 500K lines of code, so it would be difficult to check all divisions manually.

@MarkusA. Evaluating all did the trick, dsmodel.mof contained the line someVariable = 0.0/0.0. Thank you vey much!

Good to hear! I'll convert the comment to an answer, so you can accept and help others with similar problems...

One way to find the issue could be to set Advanced.OutputModelicaCode = true;, by copying the command to the command line. When translating the model the next time, Dymola will generate dsmodel.mof in the current working directory. You can get the currently used directory by typing cd or via the GUI (File -> Working Directory -> Open in File Browser/Copy Path).

The generated file dsmodel.mof contains all the (causal) statements generated from the overall model. Therefore this is a single place to look for the error. Additionally it could help to set Evaluate = true; and Advanced.EvaluateAlsoTop = true; (as an alternative you can use the GUI, via Simulation Ribbon -> Setup -> Translation, checking the top two boxes).

With a bit of luck you can search for 0.0/0.0 or something similar in dsmodel.mof.
Note: To avoid problems of that kind in Dymola it could make sense to use either the function DymolaModels.Functions.Math.divNoZero or the respective block DymolaModels.Blocks.Math.DivNoZero.
